# long enough for him to have

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

**Bitter ex-husband:** *My ex-wife has a boyfriend.*

**Another guy:** *How long has she been seeing him?*

**Bitter ex-husband:** *Long enough for him to have moved in with them.*

(them=the ex-wife and their mutual children)

**Question:**

Is "long enough for him to have..." correct in this context?

Comment: We are not supposed to correct phrasing or edit text. What is your issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

The very short answer is yes.
You might want to make it a bit clearer by saying something like

> Long enough for him to have moved in with her and our kids.

By the way, does *mutual* mean the ex-husband's children or the new boyfriend's? It is not completely  clear. Although, given the implied time frame, it is probably the former, hence the use of *our*.

Comment: The former. Thanks for your reply.